# Javascript function executes twice, Meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

This is  a simple script for horizontal fortune roulette, created using slick slider. Problem: function rollout() executed twice (and all helpers too) because template rendered twice. I'm using iron:router for routing, code:

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: "loading",
  layoutTemplate: "layout"
});
Router.map(function() {
  this.route("hello", {
    path: "/",
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe("games");
    }
  });
});
```

hello.js:

```
Session.setDefault('currentSlide', 0);
    Template.hello.events({
      'click .create': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ins = {
          gameStartTime: new Date(),
          finished: false
        }
        Games.insert({
          gameStartTime: new Date(),
          finished: "false"
        });
        Session.set("gameStatus", "waiting");
      }
    })
    Template.hello.helpers({
      currentSlide: function() {
        var value = Session.get('currentSlide');
        if (value === 25) {
          return 0;
        }
        return value;
      },
      games: function() {
        var game = Games.find();
        return game;
      },
      gameHandler: function() {
        var game = Games.findOne();
        var gameStatus = Session.get("gameStatus");
        if (game && game.finished === "false" && gameStatus === "waiting") {
          Games.update({_id: game._id}, {
            $set: {running: true}
          });

        } else if (gameStatus === "finished") {

          Meteor.call('updateGame', game._id); //remove item from collection after game over; Error here: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined; 
          console.log('game finished');
        }
        if (game && game.running === true) {
          //Set Session variable and launch roulette
          Session.set("gameStatus", "running");
          rollout(game._id);
        }
      }
    });
    var rollout = function(gameid) {
      Session.set("gameStatus", "running");
      //make div's visible. They are have display:none by default.
      document.getElementById("roulette").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "none";
      var speed = 500; //default slider speed
      Session.setDefault('speed', speed);
      var r = $('#roulette').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 7,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 0,
        speed: speed,
        draggable: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        cssEase:'linear'
      });
      var maximum = 14;
      var minimum = 0;
      var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
      var winResult = randomnumber;
      var speed = 80;
      var currentSlide = Session.get('currentSlide');
      function roll(callback) {
        Session.set('currentSlide', r.slickCurrentSlide());
        if (speed < 800) {
          speed += 20;
          r.slickSetOption("speed", speed, false);
          setTimeout(function() {
            roll(callback);
          }, 500);
        } else if (speed >= 600 && speed < 1300) {
          speed += 40;
          r.slickSetOption("speed", speed, false);
          setTimeout(function() {
            roll(callback);
          }, 300);
        } else if (speed >= 1300 && speed < 20000) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            speed += 3;
            r.slickSetOption('speed', speed, false);
            if (Session.get('currentSlide') === winResult) {
              r.slickPause();
              setTimeout(function() {
                //hide roulette div's
                document.getElementById("roulette").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("result").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "block";
                r.unslick();

                Session.set('currentSlide', 0);
                Session.set("gameStatus", "finished");
                callback(true);
                return
              }, 10000);
            } else {
              roll(callback);
            }
          }, 30)
        }  else {
          callback(true);
        }
      }
      roll(function(callback) {
        Meteor.call('updateGame', gameid); //remove item from collection
        Session.set("gameStatus", "finished");
      });
    }
```

In template i'm using spinner by sacha:spin package and it working fine.

Comment: Helpers must be stateless. If you're dealing with state do it in `onCreated` or `onRendered` handlers or in event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gameHandler function should not be in your template helpers, which are only meant to supply information to the template. Instead, that logic needs to be moved to an [autorun function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun). This autorun statement will re-run anytime a reactive datasource within it changes.

ex:

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function() {
    this.autorun(function() {
        var game = Games.findOne();
        var gameStatus = Session.get("gameStatus");
        // ...etc
    });
}
```